# In LessCSS, how can I assign true to a variable?

Tags: less

I'm new to Less, and I'm trying to implement simple mixins, but this throws a compilation error:

```
@show-image: true;

.testimg() when not (@show-image) {
    display: none;
}

img.test {
    .testimg;
}
```

It seems the compiler doesn't like my `@show-image: true` assignation. I tried assigning the number `1`, but the result was

```
img.test {
    display: none;
}
```

And that makes sense since (according to [the documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions)) *any value other than the keyword `true` is falsy*.

But can I assign the keyword `true` to my `@show-image` variable, or does it only work for with arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucho, I'm agree with you... it is young and compiler should be a LOT more descriptive, but it is not like you have to define every possible condition (although in this case of a true/false variable it appears to be the case at first)... just have to add a "default" case where fall through, like a "switch" statement:

```
@show-image: false;

.testimg() when not (@show-image){
    display: none;
}

.testimg(){
    display: inherit;
}

img.test {
    .testimg;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

It wasn't the assignation what was failing. It seems you just need to define a mixin for <s>each possible condition</s> the default condition (as [@pixshatterer pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9332338/985579)).

So in my case, I just have to do this:

```
@show-image: true;

.testimg() when not (@show-image) {
    display: none;
}

.testimg() when (@show-image) {}

img.test {
    .testimg;
}
```

This gives me two things to point out about Less. First one is about the compiler messages, they should be more descriptive; the second one is about the language itself, I think it's still too dumb to not define default cases on its own.

Don't get me wrong, I think Less is good, and it's perfect for my current needs, I'm just saying it's still to young and make you reconsider using it for big, important projects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using it quite right.  You need to pass `@show-image` into the function `.testimg()`, so the result should look something like:

```
@show-image: true;

.testimg (@show) when not (@show) {
    display: none;
}

img.test {
    .testimg(@show-image);
}
```

I tried to test this using [dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless) and it just kept giving a parse error on the closing parenthesis of the mixin definition.  It looks like it's time for a bug report there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. I'm not using the mixins wrong, you can pass arguments to them or not. With your approach, my compiler complains about this line `@show-image: true;`, if you change it for, say, `@show-image: 1;` it compiles fine, but the result is not as expected because `@show` will not be `true`. That's my point. It's not about the mixin, but about assigning the keyword `true` to a `@variable`.

Comment: @luchomolina I'm not sure that this should matter or not, but have you tried just passing true in directly to the mixin instead of using a variable for true?

Comment: I just figured it out, check out my own answer.